# How to install VLC in ubuntu 12.04 64-bit?

Tags: apt, vlc, software-installation

Can anybody help me to install VLC media player in Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-pulse`

Comment: like any other app. What is your problem in installing it?

Answer (score 7):

The simple way is, open the Ubuntu Software Center and in the search box type "VLC". There you can find the player and and you can install it by clicking on "Install", but you need Internet connection to install it, I hope you have it.

Another way is using Synaptic. Open it and type VLC in the search box as you would do for the Software Centre. Among the search results, select VLC and it will automatically select the required dependencies and install them for you.

These are the simple ways.

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Using this, I was able to play .mp4 files on a fresh 12.04 install.  From the [official site](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html), these are the instructions to install from command line:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
```

Comment: Note that `browser-plugin-vlc` is to install the version of VLC that is embedded in Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Source: [`http://www.noobslab.com/2012/03/install-vlc-201-on-ubuntu-1204.html`](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/03/install-vlc-201-on-ubuntu-1204.html)

Comment: No need of it , he can  install it directly from software center .

Comment: Maybe you could explain what advantages the version from this PPA has over the one from the official repositories.

Comment: while this particular package archive may be safe, it best to get into the habit of using the official repositories as these are vetted by many more eyes for viruses and security holes

Comment: byetoAU > the ppa will automatically update vlc